# No visible @interface for X declares the selector Y on a singleton

Tags: objective-c, singleton

So I have a singleton like this:

```
#import "SCAppManager.h"

@implementation SCAppManager

+ (instancetype)sharedApplication {
    static SCAppManager *sharedApplication = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;

    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        if (sharedApplication == nil) {
            sharedApplication = [[SCAppManager alloc] init];
        }
    });

    return sharedApplication;
}

+ (void)test {
    NSLog(@"test");
}

@end
```

And its interface is this:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface SCAppManager : NSObject

+ (instancetype)sharedApplication;
+ (void)test;

@end
```

But when a try to use the `[[SCAppManager sharedApplication] test];` in a ViewController, I get the error:

> No visible @interface for 'SCAppManager' declares the selector 'test'

I've look for all the possibilities and I already imported my singleton class correclty and declared my method in the public interface. I also searched for some answers here, but all the fix didnt work for me.

Has anyone faced this problem?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is coming because you declared `test` as a [class method](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/ClassMethod.html) not as instance method. You can call the class method by it's class name, so you should call it like:

```
[SCAppManager test];
```

Or change the method to instance method:

.h

```
@interface SCAppManager : NSObject

+ (instancetype)sharedApplication;
- (void)test;

@end
```

.m

```
@implementation SCAppManager

// Other methods

- (void)test
{
   NSLog(@"test");
}

@end
```

And use it like:

```
[[SCAppManager sharedApplication] test];
```

Comment: I was so confused with other things that I missed that. Thank you a lot, @midhun-mp !